# Moverse entre vistas sin perder datos

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5, material-design

Tengo una duda con el siguiente formulario con el que consulto unos registros.
[image: Consulta]
Al dar click en editar muestro el siguiente formulario
[image: Registro]
El formulario estaría diligenciado con todo el detalle de la consulta anterior.

Ahora lo que quiero es poner un botón que diga volver pero que al volver me muestre el formulario tal cual como estaba (con la consulta en la grilla)
¿es posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías utilizar sessionStorage (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: Hola @Anibal Ospina, osea guardar la consulta en el navegador y que cuando regrese se consulte lo que esta guardado?? Estaba intentando con un modal para no tener ese problema pero me encontre con otro lio al pasar el moda, no pude con el parametro

Comment: Hola, lo que entiendo por tu problema es que al regresar a la grilla de datos pierdes lo que definiste en los filtros (Nit y/o Estado). Lo que quieres lograr por ende es que al volver a la grilla de datos estén definidos los mismos filtros y se visualicen los mismos registros en la grilla. Podrías entonces guardar mediante sessionStorage, el valor de Nit y el valor de Estado cuando se presione el botón Consultar. Esto te obliga a verificar si el sessionStorage tiene alguna informacion al momento de volver a cargar el formulario que contiene la grilla de datos.

Comment: @AnibalOspina Muchas Gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Deberías tener una función que refresque la tabla, así una vez que el formulario es cerrado la llamas pasándole la data que tenias originalmente. Espero te sirva...